# Can't start Sinatra server on Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I've been learning how to develop on a Mac for about a year and have always been able to run a local server, for example, when developing in Ruby on Rails or Sinatra.

A few days ago I updated to Mountain Lion and I just tried to run a local server to start a Sinatra application. However, it fails with the below message:

```
== Sinatra/1.3.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

I've already checked that no other ports are in use.

What can I do to be able to run the server again?

Comment: I changed your question to ask for the real problem instead of your attempted solution (see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). "Permissions" is a very broad term here. What happens when you try to start your Rails server? Does that fail as well?

Comment: How did you determine that your ports weren't in use? Did you use netstat command or something else?

Comment: @slhck I can start the rails server

Comment: @slm I used netstat to confirm what seemed obvious (i had no servers running).

Comment: Do you know offhand what port you're trying to use? I found this issue , https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/441. Says that this message may be a "thin error".

Comment: the default for sinatra is 4567. Last night I played around with this rack tutorial (link below) that had us manually set port to a different port. I'm wondering if it made a permanent change somewhere http://rubylearning.com/blog/a-quick-introduction-to-rack/